# Loading Pgm image in pictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, image

Recently I am working on the project of breast cancer detection.So i need to load a pgm image in my picturebox.but i get a error of "Parameter  is not valid".I think the reason behind this is in my code below.

```
 public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
        {

            Image returnImage;
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);           
            returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);  //Error is in here.     
            return returnImage;
        }
```

and also i have a image stored in my database as 0x53797374656D2E44726177696E672E4269746D6170
    in this format.i searched everywhere i found that i need to remove the header and only return the image databytes to return the image..so anyone can help me to remove header from image and only return the image bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i have a image stored in my database as 0x53797374656D2E44726177696E672E4269746D6170

That's not an image.  It is a string, the hex decodes to "System.Drawing.Bitmap".  That of course sounds pretty familiar to any .NET programmer.  Clearly the code that wrote the image to the dbase is broken, looks like it used a bitmap's ToString() method.  You will need to fix that first.

Don't forget to use simple logic to seemingly undiagnosable problems, you can't store an X-ray image in 21 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn here about the format http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html. 
Also, I would suggest to get one of converters mentioned there and convert images on the fly to format that is supported.

Comment: The image class supports them natively.  Check out [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx)